# Generating single access token with Django OAuth2 Toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

I'm using the latest [Django OAuth2 Toolkit (0.10.0)](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) with Python 2.7, Django 1.8 and Django REST framework 3.3

While using the `grant_type=password`, I noticed some weird behavior that any time the user asks for a new access token:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

A **new** access token and refresh token is **created**. The **old** access and refresh token are still usable until token timeout!

**My Issues:**

- What I need is that every time a user asks for a new access token,
  the old one will become invalid, unusable and will be removed.
- Also, is there a way that the password grunt type wont create refresh
  token. I don't have any use for that in my application.

One solution I found is that [REST Framework OAuth](http://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-oauth/authentication/) provides a configuration for One Access Token at a time. I'm not eager to use that provider, but I might wont have a choice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you like to remove all previous access tokens before issuing a new one, there is a simple solution for this problem: **Make your own token view provider!**

The code bellow will probably help you to achieve that kind of functionality:

```
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken, Application
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin
from oauth2_provider.views.mixins import OAuthLibMixin
from oauth2_provider.settings import oauth2_settings

class TokenView(APIView, CsrfExemptMixin, OAuthLibMixin):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    server_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_SERVER_CLASS
    validator_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS
    oauthlib_backend_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        try:
            if username is None:
                raise User.DoesNotExist
            AccessToken.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=username), application=Application.objects.get(name="Website")).delete()
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(e.message,status=400)

        url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request)
        return Response(body, status=status, headers=headers)
```

The part you should notice is the Try-Except block. In there we finding the Access tokens and removing them. All before we creating a new one.

You can look at how to create your own [Provider using OAuthLib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/server.html#create-your-endpoint-views).
Also, this might be useful as well: [TokenView in django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/views/base.py#L155). You can see there the original Apiview. As you said, you were using this package.

As for the **refresh_token**, as previously mentioned in other answers here, you can't do what you are asking. When looking at the code of `oauthlib` password grunt type, you will see that in its initialization, refresh_token is set to True. Unless you change the Grunt type it self, it can't be done.

But you can do the same thing we did above with the access tokens. 
Create the token and then delete the refresh token.

Comment: Can I use this method to not require username and password at all?  And instead require an app password or something.

Answer (score 6):

> What I need is that every time a user asks for a new access token, the
>   old one will become invalid, unusable and will be removed.

Giving a new token when you ask for one seems like an expected behavior.  Is it not possible for you to [revoke](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_04.html#revoking-a-token) the existing one before asking for the new one?

**Update**

---

If you are determined to keep just one token  - 
The class [OAuth2Validator](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/3074e8c3f62ab7a3ccc3db2bb426414402ba041a/oauth2_provider/models.py#L175) inherits OAuthLib's `RequestValidator` and overrides the method [save_bearer_token](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/3074e8c3f62ab7a3ccc3db2bb426414402ba041a/oauth2_provider/models.py#L175).  In this method before the code related to [AccessToken model](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/3074e8c3f62ab7a3ccc3db2bb426414402ba041a/oauth2_provider/models.py#L175) instance creation and its .save() method you can query (similar to [this](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/3074e8c3f62ab7a3ccc3db2bb426414402ba041a/oauth2_provider/oauth2_validators.py#L230)) to see if there is already an AccessToken saved in DB for this user.  If found the existing token can be deleted from database.

I strongly suggest to make this change configurable, in case you change your mind in future (after all multiple tokens are issued for reasons like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340457/865587))

A more simpler solution is to have your own validator class, probably one that inherits `oauth2_provider.oauth2_validators.OAuth2Validator` and overrides `save_bearer_token`.  This new class should be given for `OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS` in `settings.py`

---

> Also, is there a way that the password grunt type wont create refresh
>   token. I don't have any use for that in my application.

Django OAuth Toolkit depends on OAuthLib.

Making refresh_token optional boils down to `create_token` method in `BearerToken` class of oAuthLib at [this line](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/blob/3d73326d4956fdf0bb8342df87c66fd13e217836/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/tokens.py#L267) and the class for password grant is [here](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/blob/3d73326d4956fdf0bb8342df87c66fd13e217836/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/grant_types/resource_owner_password_credentials.py).  As you can see the `__init__` method for this class takes `refresh_token` argument which by default is set to `True`.  This value is used in `create_token_response` method of the same class at the line

```
token = token_handler.create_token(request, self.refresh_token)
```

`create_token_response` method in [`OAuthLibCore`](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/oauth2_backends.py) class of Django OAuth toolkit is the one, I believe, calls the corresponding `create_token_response` in OAuthLib.  Observe the usage of `self.server` and its initialization in `__init__` method of this class, which has just the validator passed as an argument but nothing related to `refresh_token`.

Compare this with [OAuthLib Imlicit grant type](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/blob/3d73326d4956fdf0bb8342df87c66fd13e217836/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/grant_types/implicit.py#L231)'s `create_token_response` method, which explicitly does

```
token = token_handler.create_token(request, refresh_token=False)
```

to not create `refresh_token` at all

So, unless I missed something here, **tldr**, I don't think Django OAuth toolkit exposes the feature of optional `refresh_token`.

Comment: revoking a token is a request I don't want to make.
The goal here is to allow only one access for a user in a single machine.
I don't want to the same user will login in to places at once.

Comment: @Gal please see my Edit describing the change that needs to be done in Django Oauth Toolkit

Comment: I don't want to change the core OAuthLib Class. The whole point of using it as a package is that I won't change it. On the other hand, using Class validator could be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of just making it directly:

```
from oauthlib.common import generate_token
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken, Application
from django.utils import timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

tok = generate_token()
app = Application.objects.first()
user = User.objects.first()
access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(user=user, application=app, expires=timezone.now() + relativedelta(hours=1), token=tok)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer still fails to clear the RefreshToken. Below code should revoke both the refresh and access token.

```
from oauth2_provider.models import RefreshToken
def clear_token(user):
"""
Clear all user authorized tokens.
"""
for token in RefreshToken.objects.filter(user=user, revoked__isnull=True):
    token.revoke()
```